# Get text data along with json data on ajax success

Tags: php, jquery, json, ajax

I have developed following code which getting data from db.

```
    //get number of stores for zip code 
    $numberofstores = $resultstore = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT store,address FROM geoinfo WHERE zipcode = '$search_text'");  
    //get values from db 

    $addressArray = Array();
    $storeArray = Array();

    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($resultstore, MYSQL_ASSOC)) {
    $storeArray[] =  $row['store'];  
    $addressArray[] = $row['address']; 
}
    //return data to the client 
    echo json_encode($addressArray); 
    echo json_encode($storeArray); 


  $total =  mysqli_num_rows($resultstore);
    if(mysqli_num_rows($resultstore) != 0) {
    echo "".$total." store/s found within this area";
```

Here is my ajax call ,

```
  $(function () {

 $('#form_geocode').on('submit', function (e) {
          e.preventDefault();

          $.ajax({
            type: 'post',
            url: 'controller.php',
            dataType: 'text',
            data: $('#form_geocode').serialize(),
            success: function (data) { 
          for (var x = 0; x < data.length; x++) { 

             $("#location_results").html(data[x]+"<br>");


        }  

        }
          });

        });   

  });
```

On success output is,

```
["226 N LARCHMONT BLVD, LOS ANGELES, CA","670 S WERN AVE, LOS ANGELES, CA","3201 W 6TH ST, LOS ANGELES, CA"]["RITE AID PHARMACY","RALPHS","WALGREENS?"]3 store/s found within this area
```

My question is how can I extract 2 arrays into 2 arrays in js and store text separate variable.Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple, combine the 3 elements into a larger array before JSON encoding;

Change

```
echo json_encode($addressArray); 
echo json_encode($storeArray); 

echo "".$total." store/s found within this area";
```

to

```
echo json_encode(array($addressArray, $storeArray, "".$total." store/s found within this area"));
```

Comment: Thanks. It s fine. But how can I print 3 elements of array separately. This code out put nothing. Please see my edited code.

Comment: simply change to datatype to json

Comment: Indeed - datatype JSON, then the top level of the returned JSON will contain 3 JSON elements (addressArray, storeArray, and the total string).

Comment: If you want to be able to pull out the 3 elements by name, you could tweak it;

echo json_encode(
        array(
            'addressArray' => $addressArray, 
            'storeArray' => $storeArray, 
            'totalString' => "".$total." store/s found within this area"
        )
);

If you're unsure about how to use JSON elements in PHP, take a look at this link: http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php